# Unable to register service worker on Webstorm

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So I follow this firebase tutorial and seemingly to I do everything according to the documentation but I still get errors. [Youtube FCM Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsCBCudx58)

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAyWVXB9KFLm2ymoBoiY-TothNYgo3IrtA",
    authDomain: "fir-end-cff84.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://fir-end-cff84.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "fir-end-cff84",
    storageBucket: "fir-end-cff84.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "297653223714"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function (registration) {
        // Registration was successful
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // registration failed :(
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
}

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Have Permit');
        return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(function (token) {
        console.log(token);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

These are the logs:
[image]

And this is the project overview:

[image]

Im using the latest version of webstorm on ubuntu 16.04

Edit: I even used this repo but still have the same issue
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently to get the fcm token your localhost needs to have application server capabilities, some webstorm's localhost wont do!